# Создать матрицу

Tags: python, python-3.x, матрицы, список

Есть библиотека schedule, в которой есть заголовки title и link

```
[{'title': 'Название1', 'link': 'ссылка1.docx'}, {'title': 'название2', 'link': 'ссылка2.xls'}, {'title': 'Название3', 'link': 'ссылка3.xls'}, {'title': 'Название4', 'link': 'ссылка4.xls'}]
```

Нужно создать обычную матрицу размером len(schedule):

```
Название Ссылка

Название1 ссылка1.docx
название2 ссылка2.xls
название3 ссылка3.xls
название4 ссылка4.xls
```

Я пытался сделать вот так, но вышло нечто:

```
matrix =  ([['title'], ['link']])

for item in schedule:
    for j in range(len(matrix)):
        matrix[j][0] = [item['title']]
                
    print()
        
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        print(matrix[i][j], end = ' ')
    print()
```

Comment: Вам эта матрица для чего нужна? вывести на печать и все?

Comment: Ну бери каждый словарь и добавляй в список сразу ключ и значение

Comment: А в `schedule` содержится список со словарём с ключом 'title' и значениями?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Преобразование списка словарей в список списков

```
matrix = [[d['title'], d['link']] for d in schedule]
```

Печать "матрицы"

```
print(*map(' '.join, matrix), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

как вариант:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(i.values()) for i in schedule))

Название1 ссылка1.docx
название2 ссылка2.xls
Название3 ссылка3.xls
Название4 ссылка4.xls
```